# AWS Rust Lambda runtime, Default Request needs to be instead the ApiGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequestTypeRequest type

Tags: rust, aws-lambda, lambda, rust-tokio

I can't for the life of me think of a better way to do this:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime/tree/main

1. the Result/Request types should match the aws-lambda-rust-runtime custom runtime for the request. Their documentation doesn't have any examples, searching for this type in plaintext often finds weird unique examples that don't fit the use case or use too many custom types instead of the library types.

I've been unable to make anything reasonable work in a couple hours, so I'm hoping that somebody has experience with this in rust.

```
use lambda_http::{run, service_fn, Body, Error, Request, RequestExt, Response};
//type I want to use
use lambda_http::aws_lambda_events::apigw::ApiGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequestTypeRequest;
/// This is the main body for the function.
/// Write your code inside it.
/// There are some code example in the following URLs:
/// - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime/tree/main/examples
async fn function_handler(event: Request) -> Result<Response<Body>, Error> {
    // Extract some useful information from the request
    let who = event
        .query_string_parameters_ref()
        .and_then(|params| params.first("name"))
        .unwrap_or("world");
    let message = format!("Hello {who}, this is an AWS Lambda HTTP request");

    // Return something that implements IntoResponse.
    // It will be serialized to the right response event automatically by the runtime
    let resp = Response::builder()
        .status(200)
        .header("content-type", "text/html")
        .body(message.into())
        .map_err(Box::new)?;
    Ok(resp)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::INFO)
        // disable printing the name of the module in every log line.
        .with_target(false)
        // disabling time is handy because CloudWatch will add the ingestion time.
        .without_time()
        .init();

    run(service_fn(function_handler)).await
}
```

I tried running this code utilizing multiple google searches, searched for examples in the documentation. Personally read through the code and attempted to lift it over to the new types.

I tried using generative AI to make suggestions, but their is not enough training data or gpt3.5 isn't strong enough as of present to understand the request.

I have contacted three other engineers on my team who may have the knowledge but were unable to produce results in this area either.

I really just want the proper input and result type for the runtime impl, as it seems they do not implement the proper interfaces to work.

I have tried serializing, deserializing, etc. which doesn't work.

The only option I see is a very ugly manual extraction of all the fields and types from the raw Request type, but my gut tells me that the type being included means its somehow supported natively. I would also rather not have ugly code like that in my codebase.

Comment: Can you please create a [mre] including, what's the problem with the code? Does it not compile -> add the complete error message from the compiler (`cargo build`). Does it behave different from what you expect -> clearly state expected and actual behavior. I've read your post more than twice and could not determine what your actual question is.

Comment: I fixed it; The correct way to do this, is not to use the lambda_http types for aws_lambda_events, but to use a separate library that handles the events. Those types are there for parity.

aws_lambda_events is the correct import, albeit they are identical types, the implementations are only in aws_lambda_events.